# Windows 7 Home Premium folder sharing fails for Guest or anonymous access

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, shared-folders

Problem: our Windows 7 Home Premium PC no longer provides shared folder access over the network to non-password protected accounts, especially the Guest account.

Until the last week or so this was not an issue - we can only guess that a recent Windows update has somehow broken something.

Here are the symptoms:-

1. The PC shows as present on the network in Windows Explorer, Mac OS X Finder and Android file browser.
2. Using Explorer to browse from a Windows client: access is denied with 'you do not have permissions' warning.
3. Using Explorer from a Windows client: entering the full address into the location bar, in the form \\NAME-OF-WIN7-PC\SharedFolderName yields the correct access without any challenge for credentials.
4. From Mac OS X Finder client: folders are presented/accessible when supplied with a password protected account but never with Guest.

So in short: it appears there is guest access if the folders are addressed directly (item 3) but when browsed for via Explorer (items 2 & 4).

Hopefully that's enough information to go - can anybody shed some light please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to repair our issue by following the procedure here at:-

[MSDN Aaron Stebner's WebLog - SubInAcl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/06/17/notes-about-a-couple-of-possible-issues-while-using-the-subinacl-tool/)